# How do I Adjust Dynamic Weighted Averages?

Tags: average

I am trying to create a formula in Excel that tries to create a weighted average score for a person.  The only problem is that sometimes one or two of the components of the weighted average may not be relevant for a person.  My question is, how do I re-weight each component for them each to be mathematically correct?

For instance:

```
Grade:                 50% Weighting
Attitude:              30% Weighting
Email Responsiveness:  10% Weighting
Timeliness             10% Weighting
```

So, what happens when Email Responsiveness can no longer be a part of the weighting because no emails were ever even sent out to this person?  How would I readjust the weightings so that only Grade, Attitude, and Timeliness are factored into the weighted average and so that they maintain their relative importance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 
\frac{(0.5)\mbox{grade}+ (0.3)\mbox{attitude}+(0.1)\mbox{timeliness}}{0.9}
$$

Comment: If they get 100% Grade, 100% Attitude, and 100% timeliness, that equals (50 + 30 + 10) = 90.  90/.8 = 112.5 when in fact they got 100% total weighted average.

Comment: @user7207 Your original weights add up to 110%. This would work if "email responsiveness" was weighted at 10% instead of 20%.

Comment: @Arkamis darn you are right, I am sorry.  I fixed that!

Comment: Your denominator should be $0.9$